# Need to expose specific http url when whole application is running on https (SSL)

Tags: java, http, tomcat, ssl, https

I'm running multiple war application in same tomcat server with SSL enabled having final URLs:

1. https://192.168.110.1:8443/war1
2. https://192.168.110.1:8443/war2

Along with this, also have one directory exposed by adding `server.xml`.

```
<Context docBase="../../rawdata" path="/rw"/>
```

But trying to expose: **http**://192.168.110.1:**8080**/rw/file1.bin.
Basically, I **DONOT** want to redirect it to **https** & **8443**.

I tried adding below code in tomcat's `web.xml`

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>public</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/rw/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Entire Application</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

But the url is still getting redirected over SSL port.

How can I prevent that? Thanks in advance.